# Android Media player - play from the data device

Tags: android, media-player

I bulid an application with comment that play one song from folder in the application data..
but I want that the application turn the music on from the data device (like when you connect samsumg headphones and press on the button)
the code:

```
    public MediaPlayer song1;



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        song1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.smashing_the_opponent);

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.start:
            Log.i(tag, "Start item Clicked");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            song1.play();
        return true;
                                }
         }
```

How can I change the code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, you might want to try phrasing it more explicitely.

If you are trying to use headset controls and system-wide control listeners, have a look at [this](http://piergiu.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/android-broadcastreceiver-headset-controls/) article which explains how to implement media controls with an onKeyListener and BroadcastReceiver .

**EDIT:** *To play media that is stored on the device memory:*

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/directory/audiofile.wav"); //Path to the file on the device
```

And use either MTP, Mass Storage, or the device explorer to put the files on the device.

**EDIT2** : *To stop media and resume playing afterwards:*

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    ...//Play media, do stuff....
    int currentTime = mp.getCurrentPosition();
    mp.pause();
    ...//Media is stopped, do stuff...
    //You can even reload the whole MediaPlayer if necessary, all you need is the media (path) and millisecond CurrentTime
    mp.start();
    mp.seekTo(currentTime);
```

Comment: I will expline my self more clearly.
I want that the button will play music, but not from the folder that I crate, from the device data.

Comment: But if someone put his music on the SDcard or in some other folder ? -

Comment: I want that Media player will resume from where the device stoped